# Calculate number of days/weeks/months/years begins between two dates

Tags: perl, datetime

How to calculate then (integer) number of days/weeks/months/years beginning between two dates?

Dates are provided in epoch seconds as provided by the [`time`](https://metacpan.org/module/time) function. These examples show times formatted according to ISO 8601.

```
1 day begin  between 2014-08-24T23:59:59+0200 and 2014-08-25T00:00:01+0200   
0 day begins between 2014-08-25T00:00:01+0200 and 2014-08-25T23:59:59+0200
```

Comment: `perldoc -q date`: [perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-compare-two-dates-and-find-the-difference?)

Comment: Erm, what? Are you saying that the examples you have given are actually nothing like the real data?

Comment: You need to define what you mean by *“number of day/week/month/year begins between two dates”*. If you mean just floating-point values, with a nominal month being a twelfth of a year of 365.2425 days then that's fine. But people don't usually mean that.

Comment: I want integer values.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip: Okay, then how many months are there between 10:00pm on 31 January and 2:00am on 1 February? How many weeks between Sunday and Monday? How many years between 23:59 on 31 December 2014 and 00:01 on 1 January 2015

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip: Please also explain what you mean by *“Dates are provided in format provided by time function unlike in the examples below”*. If they're not like the examples then why did you post the examples, and what is the data *really* like?

Comment: @Borodin I have added example for day begins to the question. Between dates you provide I want to get 1 month begin (00:00 1 February) and 1 day begin (00:00 1 February).

Comment: @Borodin IMHO single integer as provided by `time` function (`perldoc -f time`) would make examples even more cryptic.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip: Okay I understand. I've amended your question: is that right? And are you counting the number of intervals that *start* between the two moments? So the number of weeks between Tuesday and Wednesday is zero, while the number of weeks between Sunday and Monday is one?

Comment: @Borodin YES if you assume that week starts on Monday (some people assume that week starts on Sunday). IMHO talking about number of week begins would be less confusing.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip: It would at least be a *definition*. But you can't choose what you implement: you need to discover what's *required*, and no one can help you until you do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the number of day/week/month/year starts between timestamps DT1 and DT2 using DateTime,

1. Find the timestamp for the first second of the day/week/month/year of which DT1 is a part.
2. Find the timestamp for the first second of the day/week/month/year of which DT2 is a part.
3. Find the differences in days/weeks/months/years between those two timestamps.

---

```
use DateTime qw( );

# Or maybe << time_zone => 'local' >>?
my $dt1 = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => ..., time_zone => '+0200' );
my $dt2 = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => ..., time_zone => '+0200' );

# Some days in some time zones don't have a midnight, so switch to 'floating'.
# before truncating. The dts must all be in the same time zone beforehand.
my $date1 = $dt1->clone;
my $date2 = $dt2->clone;
$_->set_time_zone('floating')->truncate( to => 'day' )
   for $date1, $date2;

my $day_starts = $date2->delta_days($date1)->in_units('days');

my $week_starts = do {                   # Sunday starts
   my $date1_week_start = $date1->clone;
   my $date2_week_start = $date2->clone;

   $_->subtract( days => $_->day_of_week % 7 )
      for $date1_week_start, $date2_week_start;

   $date2_week_start->delta_days($date1_week_start)->in_units('weeks')
};

my $month_starts = do {
   my $date1_month_start = $date1->clone;
   my $date2_month_start = $date2->clone;

   $_->truncate( to => 'month' )
      for $date1_month_start, $date2_month_start;

   $date2_month_start->delta_md($date1_month_start)->in_units('months')
};

my $year_starts = abs( $date2->year - $date1->year );

printf("%d years, %d months, %d weeks and %d days begin between %s and %s\n",
   $year_starts,
   $month_starts,
   $week_starts,
   $day_starts,
   $date1->ymd,
   $date2->ymd,
);
```

---

```
my $dt1 = DateTime->new( year => 2014, month => 8, day => 23 );
my $dt2 = DateTime->new( year => 2014, month => 8, day => 24 );
```

gives

```
0 years, 0 months, 1 weeks and 1 days begin between 2014-08-23 and 2014-08-24
```

and

```
my $dt1 = DateTime->new( year => 2014, month => 1, day => 31 );
my $dt2 = DateTime->new( year => 2014, month => 2, day =>  1 );
```

gives

```
0 years, 1 months, 0 weeks and 1 days begin between 2014-01-31 and 2014-02-01
```

---

Notes:

- I assume there are no days missing between the dates in question.
- It doesn't matter if the earlier time stamp is in `$dt1` or `$dt2`.